# AWS - JavaScript - CRUD operations on DynamoDB with authenticated Cognito user

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Trying to do the CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) on DynamoDB tables that have specific user permissions.

So I've created the IAM policy for my table and the user roles associated with the policy. Ive also created my users and identity pools. Whats left I believe is for me to do the actual coding.

So I found this CRUD SDK offered by amazon:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Js.03.html

The SDK offers functions to do the CRUD operations on the desired tables. This is great. Although, I'm not really sure how to integrate a specific user, based on the permissions I've configured for the table.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js">.
</script>

<script>
AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000',
  // accessKeyId default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB. 
  // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
  accessKeyId: "fakeMyKeyId",
  // secretAccessKey default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB. 
  // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
  secretAccessKey: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

function conditionalDelete() {
    var table = "Movies";
    var year = 2015;
    var title = "The Big New Movie";

    var params = {
        TableName:table,
        Key:{
            "year":year,
            "title":title
        },
        ConditionExpression:"info.rating <= :val",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":val": 5.0
        }
    };

    docClient.delete(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "The conditional delete failed: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "The conditional delete succeeded: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
        }
    });
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="conditionalDelete" type="button" value="Conditional Delete" onclick="conditionalDelete();" />
<br><br>
<textarea readonly id= "textarea" style="width:400px; height:800px">
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

This is really helpful code. Although in the config.update they require the `accessKeyId: "fakeMyKeyId"` and the `secretAccessKey: "fakeSecretAccessKey"` How would I replace this with an authenticated Cognito user?

Does anyone have any ideas or resources for this? I've looked everywhere. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you authenticate a user, you can then use the [GetCredentialsForIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html) method to get temporary access key, secret key and session token. You use these three credentials to access AWS resources. So you will have to update your config with these. Keep in mind that these keys will expire after an hour.

Comment: thank you, it seems to return the desired info. however, I don't understand what identity provider name should be. would it be "Cognito"? `Logins: {
    '<IdentityProviderName>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<IdentityProviderName>': ... */
  }`

Comment: also how come I can access these tokens, but im not providing any security information (username/pass)?

Comment: @FlightHoldings There are two main roles in cognito. Unauth role and auth role. These are automatically created when you create identity pool. You can go and edit the permissions for these roles in IAM. So when you get credentials without using username/pass you get credentials for the unauth role. When you use username/password you get credentials for auth role.

Comment: and for the identity provider name it should be `cognito-idp.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<USER POOL ID>`: idtoken

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html
This is the api you use to actually log in and get the various tokens (id token, access token and refresh token)

Comment: All this is quite complicated which is why there are libraries that simplify it. I highly recommend you find a library to do all this for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know any libraries I can use?

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/README.md

This is the most popular one.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to the following link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html

2- Go to the JavaScript section

3- Adapt to your code

4- Change your IdentityPoolID (cognito-> identityPool -> console -> copy the ID)